# How to add amount Bonus to cart using discount code

Tags: magento-1.7, discount

I am trying to build buying store. Therefore, it is opposite traditional website. I need to create coupon which gives bonus to customer who sell product to me. However, Discount code don't allow to do that. Do you know where i need to change phtml,xml, or php file or files need to change.

For example,

If customers sell their items using promotion code, we will give extra 5$. 
But I want to know which code they used.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use custom extension for that. either you need to create or purchase from third party. if you have that one already then please mention.